# PDF-To-HTML Post Action

Tags: php

I'm fairly new to PHP because i'm an Android programmer but i need to convert a pdf file to html. I don't want to use any external API's because they are way to pricey. Now I would like to use http://www.convertpdftohtml.com to convert my pdf to html. However that site does not have any API and only works manually. According to Tomer W. it is possible to simulate a POST action for the website and doing it automatically. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9592926/online-pdf-to-html-conversion-api

Now i'm wondering how i would be able to do this. (I don't have a lot of knowledge about PHP) but i know people who might help me to get it working (if i have some kind of pseudo code)

Comment: Check out curl, that's how you can simulate post-actions.  The php-manual has a good section on it.  You can use `curl_setopt`with `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`.

Comment: You can simulate a post to any website or service, the question is: does it violate their Terms of Service.

Comment: If you are able to install server software. Lookup a tool called "pdftohtml" i believe it is. Then you can use a system call. This way you don't become reliant on external services.

Comment: Thanks all. 1. Ok thanks! Any tutorials available on how to integrate or work with Curl? 2. I can't find anything in their TOS as long as i give credits. 3. I already find pdftohtml but i don't understand how to integrate it. (http://www.articlediary.com/article/php-script-for-pdf-to-html-conversion-125.html)

Answer (score 0):

This may soon be unnecessary. Mozilla have incorporated [pdf.js](https://mozillalabs.com/en-US/pdfjs/) into Firefox 19